# Conditionally Convergent Series

Tags: real-analysis

How can you prove that the series formed by the positive terms of a conditionally convergent series is divergent and then do the same for the series for the negative terms?

Answer (score 3):

Let $$\sum c_n$$ be conditionally convergent.

Let $c_n^+:=\max(c_n,0)$, $c_n^{-}:=-\min(c_n,0)$

Then $c_n^+,c_n^{-}\geq 0$ and $$c_n=c_n^{+}-c_n^{-}$$ You have that $$\sum|c_n|$$ diverges.

And $$|c_n|=c_n^{+}+c_n^{-}$$

Suppose that both converged. Then what would happen to  $$\sum|c_n|=\sum c_n^{+}+\sum c_n^{-}\text{ ? }$$

Suppose one diverged, but the other didn't. What would happen to $$\sum c_n=\sum c_n^{+}-\sum c_n^{-}\text{ ? }$$

Comment: +1 for explaining the equivalence of [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConditionalConvergence.html)'s definition for conditionally convergent.

Comment: @genepeer Never encountered that definition before. Curious.